# In RxJs how can you make a throttled buffer operator?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have the following need:

I want to throttle a function call using rxjs with both `leading` and `trailing` set to true.  However, I don't want to ignore the fn calls that were skipped; I want to include the output of all function calls that as an array, both at the beginning and ending of the throttle.  Kind of like combining `throttle` and `buffer`

To give a better example:

I only want to emit the number of clicks every 1 second.  If there is a long pause, when the next click happens, emit that click's x and y right away (in an array as if it was buffered).  All clicks since that first click up until 1 second, will be observed as an array one that second arrives.

Here is some code I tried but doesnt seem to work, tryable on [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/throttledbuffer-l7pgn?file=/src/index.js:0-634):

```js
import { pipe, asyncScheduler, interval } from "rxjs";
import { publish, throttleTime, buffer, take } from "rxjs/operators";

const throttledBuffer = (throttleTimeMs) => {
  return pipe(
    // publish this observable so it can be shared
    publish((observable$) => {
      // get invokations, and throttle them
      const throttleCalls$ = observable$.pipe(
        throttleTime(throttleTimeMs, asyncScheduler, {
          leading: true,
          trailing: true
        }),
        
      );

      // buffer observable, emitting an array of accumulated values for each fn call at each observed throttle
      return observable$.pipe(
        buffer(throttleCalls$)
      );
    })
  );
};


const clicks$ = interval(50);


clicks$.pipe(throttledBuffer(100),take(4)).subscribe({
  next: (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  }
});
```

In the above code snippet, I would expect to have the result:

```js
[0]
[1, 2]
[3]
[4, 5]
```

However, this is what happens:

```js
[]
[0,1,2]
[]
[3,4,5]
```

It seems as if the buffer is occuring before the throttle can emit something; or after it and skips it.  Has anyone succeeded in making a custom operator like this?

Comment: I tried something [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/throttledbuffer-forked-4y8qe?file=/src/index.js) and it seems to match the requirements, but not the expected output. I think I'm missing something. In your case, why is it `[0, 1]`, instead of `[0]` and then `[1,2]`? I'd say that `0` comes after a *long pause*(-> `[0]`) and since that moment, `1` and `2` are observed, until that second elapses.

Comment: yes you are riight my expected output is wrong.  the answer seems to work well, thank you!  can you create an answer here - and better explain what the code is doing with comments (or method names)?

Comment: I implemented something using a combination of an observable and `setTimeout()`: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awezgr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TLDR;

Here would be an approach:

```js
const throttledBuffer = (throttleTimeMs) => {
  return pipe(
    publish((observable$) => {
      const throttleCalls$ = observable$.pipe(
        // tap((v) => console.log("in throttle", v)),
        throttleTime(throttleTimeMs, asyncScheduler, {
          leading: true,
          trailing: true
        }),
        // tap(() => console.log("after throttle"))
      );

      const src$ = observable$.pipe(share());
      return merge(
        src$.pipe(ignoreElements()),
        src$.pipe(/* tap(console.log), */ buffer(throttleCalls$))
      );
    })
  );
};

const clicks$ = interval(50);
clicks$.pipe(throttledBuffer(100), take(4)).subscribe({
  next: (value) => {
    console.log("p", value);
  }
});

/* 
console output:

p 
(1) [0]
p 
(2) [1, 2]
p 
(1) [3]
p 
(2) [4, 5]
*/
```

*You can uncomment the `tap`s in order to examine what's going on.*

*A working demo can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/throttledbuffer-forked-4y8qe?file=/src/index.js:188-752).*

---

### Why the above solution works and what went wrong with the previous one

#### Understanding the `publish` operator

First, it's important to highlight [how the `publish` operator works](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/publish.ts#L81):

```js
export function publish<T, R>(selector?: OperatorFunction<T, R>): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> | OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  return selector ? connect(selector) : multicast(new Subject<T>());
}
```

In this case, we're interesting in the `selector` approach. But, as you can see, if you were to use simply `publish()`, it would use `multicast` with `Subject`. As a side note, `publishReplay` uses `multicast` too, but with a `ReplaySubject` instead of `Subject`.

The `connect` function is defined [as follows](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/f46ee6e0caf2908f1fd8500ab4d7c03f52d24e2e/src/internal/operators/connect.ts#L103-L106):

```js
// `source` - the further-up observable in the chain
// `subscriber` - the newly created subscriber
/* 
To get a better understanding of what `subscriber` and `source` really are, let's consider this quick example

const o$ = new Observable(subscriber => {});
o$.pipe(
  map(...),
).subscribe({ next: v => console.log('hello', v) })

In the `map`'s implementation, when the `map` observable is subscribed, it will call again `source.subscribe(someSubscriber)`.
In that case, `someSubscriber` is a `{ next: v => console.log('hello', v) }`(roughly) and `source` is `o$`.
So, in `subscriber => {}` from `Observable`'s callback, the `subscriber` will actually be `someSubscriber`.
*/

// It is a `Subject` instance
const subject = connector();

from(selector(fromSubscribable(subject))).subscribe(subscriber);
subscriber.add(source.subscribe(subject));
```

`fromSubscribable(subject)` will return an `Observable` instance that, when subscribed to, the subscriber will be added to the `subject`'s subscribers list. So, the argument to the callback function your provided to `publish` will be that `Observable` instance I mentioned before. The point of all of this is to know that every **subscriber created inside that callback** will be part of the `subject`'s subscribers list. So, with `subscriber.add(source.subscribe(subject))`, the `subject` will subscribe to the `source`, meaning that all the values which come from the `source` will be received by the `subject` in use, which also means that those values will be **sent to all of the subscribers in that list**.

So, the gist is that the **order** in which you create your subscribers in that callback function is important.

#### Why the problem occurs

Let's now see what the problem was in the first place:

```js
const throttledBuffer = (throttleTimeMs) => {
  return pipe(
    publish((observable$) => {
      const throttleCalls$ = observable$.pipe(
        throttleTime(throttleTimeMs, asyncScheduler, {
          leading: true,
          trailing: true
        })
      );

      return observable$.pipe(buffer(throttleCalls$));
    })
  );
};

const clicks$ = interval(50);

clicks$.pipe(throttledBuffer(100), take(4)).subscribe({
  next: (value) => {
    console.log("p", value);
  }
});

/* 
console output:

p
[]
p 
(3) [0, 1, 2]
p 
[]
p 
(3) [3, 4, 5]
*/
```

By returning `observable$.pipe(buffer(throttleCalls$))`, is essentially the same as doing

```js
observable$.pipe(buffer(throttleCalls$)).subscribe(subscriber /* #1 */);
```

And here is, finally :), the problem. The problem is that `throttleCalls$` will be subscribed first, because the concept behind this can be boiled down to `f(g(x))`, where `g(x)` will be called first. Because `throttleCalls$`is subscribed first, it means that that `subject` instance will register this subscriber as the **first one** in the list. As a result, the `subscriber#1` will be the second one. This means that when the source emits something, the subscriber created from `throttleCalls$`' subscription will be the **first one** to receive the value, and **that's why** you'll get an **empty array** first.
Remember that a `Subject` sends the values to its subscribers synchronously. This means that immediately after the buffer emitted `[]`, the second subscriber will receive the value and the `buffer`'s array will be `[0]`. Since a second has not yet elapsed, `1` and `2` will make it, and when the second eventually elapses, the `buffer`'s array will be `[0, 1, 2]`. Then, again, `3` is emitted, but the **first subscriber** to receive it will be the one which belongs to `throttleCalls$`, which is the `buffer`'s notifier, so, again, we'd get an empty array.

So, the problem is that the order in which the subscribers are added into the `Subject`'s subscribers list is not the one we want.

#### Why the solution works

Let's see once again the solution from the **TLDR** section:

```js
const throttledBuffer = (throttleTimeMs) => {
  return pipe(
    publish((observable$) => {
      const throttleCalls$ = observable$.pipe(
        // tap((v) => console.log("in throttle", v)),
        throttleTime(throttleTimeMs, asyncScheduler, {
          leading: true,
          trailing: true
        }),
        // tap(() => console.log("after throttle"))
      );

      const src$ = observable$.pipe(share());
      return merge(
        src$.pipe(ignoreElements()),
        src$.pipe(/* tap(console.log), */ buffer(throttleCalls$))
      );
    })
  );
};

const clicks$ = interval(50);
clicks$.pipe(throttledBuffer(100), take(4)).subscribe({
  next: (value) => {
    console.log("p", value);
  }
});

/* 
console output:

p 
(1) [0]
p 
(2) [1, 2]
p 
(1) [3]
p 
(2) [4, 5]
*/
```

With the bit of knowledge acquired from the previous section, let's go step by step to understand what's going on. We know the problem was the order, so we could work on that. We can get the order we want by using `merge` like this:

```js
merge(
  // `ignoreElements()` will ignore `next`, but will let `error`/`complete` notification in
  // By providing this as the first argument, the we can be sure that the first emitted value 
  // will be **first** part of the buffer, and then the `buffer`'s notifier will emit
  src$.pipe(ignoreElements()),

  // Ensuring the `buffer`'s notifier is the **second** in the list
  src$.pipe(/* tap(console.log), */ buffer(throttleCalls$))
);
```

However, there is one more thing to do in order to make sure everything works as expected, which is

```js
const src$ = observable$.pipe(share());
```

what `share()` does is to add a `Subject` instance between the data consumers(the 2 `merge`s arguments) and the data producer(`observable$`).

The reason we needed this is best explained with the help of this little diagram:

```
                    s1 (the `observable$` argument)
                  /  \
                s2    throttleCalls$
                /  \
(1)ignoreElements    (2)buffer(throttleCalls$)

s2 - the Subject we got from `share()`
```

so, when `s1` receives a value, `s2` will receive it first, then `(1)`, then `(2)`, and then `throttleCalls$`. And this is what we want, because we first add to the buffer, and after that the `buffer`'s notifier(which is `throttleCalls$`) emits.

Now you might wonder, why wouldn't it work like this?

```js
// const src$ = observable$.pipe(share());
return merge(
  observable$.pipe(ignoreElements()),
  observable$.pipe(/* tap(console.log), */ buffer(throttleCalls$))
);
```

The diagram for the above snippet would look like this:

```
               s1 (the `observable$` argument)
              /  \
(1)ignoreElements  (2)buffer(throttleCalls$)
```

Well, we came back to the same problem we had initially, `throttleCalls$` is subscribed first, because `(1)` and `(2)` are **completely independent**. The subscribers list would (roughly) look like this:

```
[
  ignoreElements,
  throttleCalls$,
  (2) - the `buffer`'s source
]
```

Comment: amazing and detailed answer, thank you for taking the time to put this together!!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Here would be another approach

```
const throttleTimeMs = 2000;
const subject = new Subject();

const pipeline1 = subject
    .pipe(
        throttleTime(throttleTimeMs, undefined, { trailing: true, leading: true }),
        share(),
    )

const pipeline2 = subject
    .pipe(
        buffer(pipeline1),
    )

const subscription = pipeline1
    .pipe(
        exhaustMap(() => pipeline2),
        filter(tap => tap.length > 1),
        tap(tap => {
            console.log(tap)
            //Your logic goes here
        })
    )
    .subscribe()
```